# Joins in Hibernate and its use

Tags: java, hibernate

What is join in HQL and where shall it be used?

Have gone through tutorial.Majorly three of them used as follows:

```
Inner Join
Left Outer Join
Right Outer Join
```

Read few tutorials yet unable to understand.

Comment: Could you narrow down your question? You're basically asking someone to write you a personalized tutorial, without knowing what you didn't understand about the other tutorials you found.

Comment: @Kenster Apologies if you felt so.I was not able to understand the concept for join which is now pretty clear from example of accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join in HQL is same like the `SQL joins`. In SQL join is used to join two tables to return matching data. In HQL join is between Parent entity and the child entity (Usually on a ForeignKey of a parent primary key).

Person table

```
person_id | name | dob
```

Address table

```
address_id | address_line1 | state | zip | person_id
```

A SQL Join looks like

```
Select * from person p join address a on p.person_id = a.person_id and p.person_id = 10
```

This will return data like following if a person has more than one address

```
person_id | name | dob | address_id  | address_line1 | state | zip   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
10          Jack  10/25  22            223 elk blvd    AZ      54444
10          Jack  10/25  244            223 NY blvd     TX      54344
```

A HQL join looks like

```
from Person p join p.address
```

and it returns `Person` entity with a list of `addresses` in it.

```
Person{
    List address = [ Address{ (this is Object)  }, Address{(This is object)}]

}
```